# MSSQL BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как с помощью **BULK INSERT** загружать данные из файла в таблицу c обработкой?

**Структура таблицы:**
`Name;Value;`

**Как выглядит файл:**

```
//Имя:Значение1:Значение2:Значение3:  
Курица:190.3:160.2:190.3  
Котлета:190.3:160.2:190.3
```

**Как должно быть в таблице:**

```
Курица;190.3
Курица;160.3
Курица;190.3
```

Comment: В какой кодировке файл ? А то в документации пишут, что bulk не поддерживает UTF-8...

Comment: @Mike, В файле только цифры. Данные примеры абстрактные. Можно не смотреть на кодировку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько мне удалось понять, непосредственно `BULK INSERT` не умеет разворачивать одну строку входного файла в несколько строк таблицы. Однако, есть конструкция [`OPENROWSET`](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190312(v=sql.105).aspx), которая позволяет использовать произвольный файл в виде таблицы в операции `SELECT`.

Для начала нам понадобится описать формат входного файла с помощью подобной XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
 <RECORD>  
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=":" MAX_LENGTH="20"/>  
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=":" MAX_LENGTH="20"/>  
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=":" MAX_LENGTH="20"/>  
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Val1" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="10" SCALE="2"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Val2" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="10" SCALE="2"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Val3" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="10" SCALE="2"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

После чего мы можем произвести загрузку данных с помощью подобного запроса:

```
insert into BulkTable(Name,Value)
select Name,
       case n when 1 then Val1
              when 2 then Val2
              when 3 then Val3
       end
  from OPENROWSET(BULK  'D:\MSSQL\data.txt',
                  FORMATFILE='D:\MSSQL\format.xml'
                 ) AS t,
       (select 1 union select 2 union select 3) as n(n)
```